# excel vba vlookup referencing separate workbook without name

Tags: excel, vba

I want a code in one workbook that uses vlookup to reference another workbook without specific identification.

So I have to use vlookup almost every month for about 20 different reports and I want to automate it, but because the names and every other type of information is different, I **cannot** use names or indexes.

I checked other posts and mainly the answers that I've seen were ones that referenced a name or instead of a name, an index. Because the names are going to be different every time I won't be able to reference to them, it won't be an automated process. I was thinking about looking for some reference like "ActiveWorkbook." The "ActiveWorkbook" reference only targets one workbook however there is one workbook where the data is going to be inputted and one workbook where the source data is.

Comment: A suggestion could be to whip up a quick userform asking for the names of the sheets you want to use, if the only difference is the names. Additionally, you may be able to reserve two cells in which users can enter the sheet names.

Comment: Does the target workbook have more than one worksheet?  If it does have more than one worksheet, is there something special about the worksheet you want? For example, can you check row 1 for known header values?

Comment: @partyhatpanda in the vlookup function vba or otherwise, it requires that I reference a column of data that I want to look up a value from. This value is in another workbook so when I use a macro, I have to reference the other workbook before I can reference the column of data that I want. 
I'm not quite sure how a list of sheet names will enable me to reference the data I want, maybe because of lack of experience. Could you explain it further?

Comment: @tony dallimore the workbooks only have one worksheet in them. I need to reconcile two reports so I need to check if one reports values are the same as another. The workbook I want has several columns of data I want to bring into another workbook, to make it easier to reconcile. The amount of money, the type of payment, and the cashier. All of this is looked up by using the ID number on the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you have started looking for useful pieces of code before learning the basics.  This is a very common problem and many are in much worse shape than you.  There are many online Excel VBA tutorials.  Try a few; find one that matches your learning style and finish it.  I prefer books to online tutorials.  I visited a large library; reviewed their Excel VBA primers; borrowed the most promised; completed my review at home and bought the one I liked best as a permanent reference.

I need you to pick a folder containing at least three workbooks which I will call workbooks A, B and C.  Workbook A must be macro enabled and must have a reference to the Microsoft Runtime Scripting library.  At least one workbook should have multiple worksheets. At least one worksheet should have values in row 1.

Copy `DemoWbkWsht` to a new module in workbook A.  In line 49 replace "SheetsMove.xlsm" with the name of workbook C.

Open workbook B.  Go to “Run macros” and run macro `DemoWbkWsht`.  That is, run a macro in another workbook.  Macro `DemoWbkWsht` creates a file named “DemoWbkWsht.txt” in the folder.  Work down the file and the macro reviewing the output and the statements I used to create that output.  I believe I have demonstrated everything you need to know.  Come back with questions as necessary but, the more you can understand on your own, the faster you will develop.

The points I particularly want you to notice:

- The difference between `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook`
- Workbooks.Open changes `ActiveWorkbook` but not `ThisWorkbook`.
- How you can loop through the open workbooks or create an array of
  workbook references and loop through them.
- How you can loop through every worksheet in a workbook.
- How every workbook has an `ActiveSheet`.  This is the worksheet activate when the workbook was last saved.  That was why I asked if these workbooks had more than one worksheet.  If a workbook has only one worksheet, that worksheet must be the active worksheet.
- How you can look at any cell within any worksheet within any open workbook.  I have used this ability to list the values in row 1 of every worksheet. These values are column headings in most worksheets.  This was my other question: can you identify the target worksheet by its headings?  I doubt you need the user’s help, I believe your macro can identify the worksheets you need to access itself.

Good luck

```
Option Explicit
Sub DemoWbkWsht()

  ' Needs reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime library. See Tools->References.

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim DiagFile As TextStream
  Dim Fso As New FileSystemObject
  Dim InxWbk As Long
  Dim InxWsht As Long
  Dim Path As String
  Dim WbkA As Workbook
  Dim WbkB As Workbook
  Dim WbkC As Workbook
  Dim WbkCrnt As Variant

  ' Updating the screen while updating a worksheet is the easiest way of
  ' ensuring your macro takes FOREVER to run. ALWAYS include this statement
  ' even if you do not think it is necessary.
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ' Create reference to workbook holding this macro
  Set WbkA = ThisWorkbook

  ' Record path of workbook holding macro.
  Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

  ' Create the text file to which diagnostic file will be output within
  ' the folder holding the workbook holding this macro
  Set DiagFile = Fso.CreateTextFile(Path & "DemoWbkWsht.txt", True, False)

  ' List open workbooks.  Identify workbook B.
  DiagFile.WriteLine "***** Workbooks open when macro started"
  For InxWbk = 1 To Workbooks.Count
    DiagFile.WriteLine "  " & Workbooks(InxWbk).Name
    If Workbooks(InxWbk).Name <> WbkA.Name Then
      Set WbkB = Workbooks(InxWbk)
    End If
  Next

  ' List special workbooks.
  DiagFile.WriteLine "***** Special workbooks"
  DiagFile.WriteLine "  ActiveWorkbook: " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
  DiagFile.WriteLine "    ThisWorkbook: " & ThisWorkbook.Name
  DiagFile.WriteLine "      Workbook A: " & WbkA.Name
  DiagFile.WriteLine "      Workbook B: " & WbkB.Name

  Set WbkC = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & "SheetsMove.xlsm")

  DiagFile.WriteLine "***** Special workbooks  after open of workbook C."
  DiagFile.WriteLine "  ActiveWorkbook: " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
  DiagFile.WriteLine "    ThisWorkbook: " & ThisWorkbook.Name
  DiagFile.WriteLine "      Workbook A: " & WbkA.Name
  DiagFile.WriteLine "      Workbook B: " & WbkB.Name
  DiagFile.WriteLine "      Workbook C: " & WbkC.Name

  ' List worksheets in workbooks A, B and C
  For Each WbkCrnt In VBA.Array(WbkA, WbkB, WbkC)
    With WbkCrnt
      DiagFile.WriteLine "***** Worksheets in workbook """ & .Name & """"
      With WbkCrnt
        For InxWsht = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
          DiagFile.WriteLine PadL(InxWsht, 4) & " " & .Worksheets(InxWsht).Name
        Next
        DiagFile.WriteLine "  ActiveWorksheet: " & .ActiveSheet.Name
      End With
    End With
  Next

  ' List worksheets in workbooks A, B and C
  For Each WbkCrnt In VBA.Array(WbkA, WbkB, WbkC)
    With WbkCrnt
      DiagFile.WriteLine "***** Worksheets in workbook """ & .Name & """"
      For InxWsht = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
        DiagFile.WriteLine PadL(InxWsht, 4) & " " & .Worksheets(InxWsht).Name
      Next InxWsht
      DiagFile.WriteLine "  ActiveSheet: " & .ActiveSheet.Name
    End With  ' WbkCrnt
  Next WbkCrnt

  ' List values from row 1 of worksheets in workbooks A, B and C
  For Each WbkCrnt In VBA.Array(WbkA, WbkB, WbkC)
    With WbkCrnt
      DiagFile.WriteLine "***** Values, if any, from row 1 of each worksheet in workbook """ & .Name & """"
      For InxWsht = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
        With .Worksheets(InxWsht)
          DiagFile.WriteLine PadL(InxWsht, 4) & " Worksheet: " & .Name
          ColLast = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
          For ColCrnt = 1 To ColLast
            If .Cells(1, ColCrnt).Value <> "" Then
              DiagFile.WriteLine Space(5) & ColCode(ColCrnt) & "1=" & .Cells(1, ColCrnt).Value
            End If
          Next ColCrnt
        End With  ' .Worksheets(InxWsht)
      Next InxWsht
    End With  ' WbkCrnt
  Next WbkCrnt

  WbkC.Close SaveChanges:=False

  DiagFile.Close

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Function ColCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim PartNum As Long

  '  3Feb12  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  ' 28Oct16  Renamed ColCode to match ColNum.

  If ColNum = 0 Then
    Debug.Assert False
    ColCode = "0"
  Else
    ColCode = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      ColCode = Chr(65 + PartNum) & ColCode
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

End Function
Public Function PadL(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with leading PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Sep15 Coded
  ' 20Dec15 Added code so overlength strings are not truncated
  ' 10Jun16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadL = Str
  Else
    PadL = Right$(String(PadLen, PadChr) & Str, PadLen)
  End If

End Function
```